# Webcam doesn't work with openCV 1.0 C (CodeBlocks)

Tags: c, opencv, codeblocks, webcam, vision

I got a problem, I want a window with what my webcam displays; but what I have is a windows with ... a black 
I tried to got image dimensions, but it's a 0x0
My webcam is good, It works with displaying of Windows!!
this's ma code
(Windows 7 x64 bits)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    IplImage* img;
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM (CV_CAP_ANY);
    if (!capture)
        return 10;

    cvNamedWindow("video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    char key = 'a';

    if (!cvGrabFrame(capture))
        return 20;

    while (key != 'q'){
        img = cvRetrieveFrame(capture);
        cvShowImage("video", img);

        key = cvWaitKey(60);

        if (!cvGrabFrame(capture))
            key = 'q';

    }
    cvDestroyAllWindows();
    img = NULL;
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: downvoted for 'living under a rock'. you neither should use opencv1.0, nor it's deprecated c-api. the opencv world has moved on to 2.4.9 and a c++ api, please use that instead.

Comment: I'm novice .... it's for studies, we have to use the v1 :/

Comment: ^^ understood. please try to convince your teachers/mentors to reconsider that decision. again, to do anything useful with opencv in 2014, you will have to use the modern version. any effort spent on learning the outdated stuff is wasted.

Comment: @BiLLiXx I'm curious, what could be the reason one _has_ to use version 1?

Comment: Dunnow; people are bizarres ...
Anyway, is the version what causes me this problem ? (not getting image from wabcam)

Comment: Can be a lot of reasons: video codecs not installed on your machine, too old OpenCV version not supporting your camera...
Instead of returning after cvGrabFrame(capture), try to print out a message to console there and see if it is really grabbing frames.